# Show Alert Dialog from Activity after activity returned result from a Fragment

Tags: android

The title might not be very clear, its kind of hard to explain in a short title. But here is the problem.

I have an activity, `MainActivity` which then shows an activity at start to show `FragmentA`. In `MainActivity` there is a menu that is shown which is accessible via FragmentA. From the menu in FragmentA the user clicks on Generate Password which then calls another activity called `GeneratePassword` called using `startActivityForResult`. When the user presses the submit button the user is then sent back to FragmentA and the function `onActivityResult` within the `MainActivity`. Within this function, I then make use of a common class which allows me to show an AlertDialog with Yes and No Buttons. OnActivityResult works fine if I take out the common.showYesNoDialog() if statement, but when this is being used I get an exception

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Below is the code that starts the GeneratePassword Activity

```
Intent generatePasswrodIntent = new Intent(mMainActivity, GeneratePassword.class);
                startActivityForResult(generatePasswrodIntent, AddNewLogin.GENERATE_PASSWORD);
                return(true);
```

Below is the code that sets the result from the GeneratePassword activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("password", generatePassword.generatePassword());
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(AddNewLogin.GENERATE_PASSWORD, intent);
        finish();
```

Below is the code from the onActivityResult that shows the alert dialog

```
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();

        String password = bundle.getString("password");
        Log.d("PASSWORD", password);
        if (common.showYesNoDialog("Your Generated Password Is:\n " + password + "\nDo you want to copy this to the clipboard?", false))
        {
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(password);
        }
```

Below is the YesNoDialog function, but I know this works fine as I have used it in several places within my app without problem.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message mesg)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setCancelable(isCancelable);
            builder.setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialogResult = true;
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialogResult = false;
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        try
        {
            Looper.loop();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException ex)
        {
            Log.d("Dialog Error", ex.toString());
        }
        return dialogResult;
```

And below is how I am initialising the common class

```
Common common = new Common(getApplicationContext());
```

Instead of getApplicationContext, I've tried using `this` but doesn't make any difference.

I just don't understand what is happening here.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `showYesNoDialog()`. What does the boolean parameter for your showYesNoDialog() method do?

Comment: I know there is nothing wrong with this function, I've used it many other parts of the app, the issue is the alert dialog can't display. For reference the boolean parameter isCancelable is to determine whether or not the AlertDialog can be cancelled via the user pressing the back button as used on the line ``builder.setCancelable(isCancelable);``

Comment: Oh, ok. It isn't giving you specific lines in LogCat right? If not, then it beats me. Sorry.